# .net architecture for module based solution

Tags: asp.net-mvc, architecture, mef, prism-4

I'm in the research/planning phase of a project (.Net c#, mvc or silverlight). It's a web project that offers certain services bundled into packages. The client can sign up for one of the different packages.

I'm looking for any suggestions on which architecture/framework to use for this kind of project. I want the ability to load or unload modules depending on the package. I also want to be able to enable and disable features within the packages themselves.

The modules have to be highly portable and plug-able into different clients. I know there are MEF and Prism but I haven't really worked with both. I also read about MVC and Areas. I would rather design everything from scratch and not depend on a third party if the task is simple enough. I just don't know where or how to start.

I appreciate the suggestions.
MG

Answer (score 0):

You can forget about unloading. You have to use seperate appdomsins to be able to unload modules. And that's nothing that I would ever try with a ASP.NET website.

You have to get used to the thought that all modules are loaded at all times. You can use role based security to control if a user can use a module or not (one or more roles per plugin).

As for loading things dynamically: I've written an article about how you can create a plugin system using my Griffin.MvcContrib: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/386674/ASP-NET-MVC-3-plug-in-architecture-using-Griffin-M